# Is it possible to execute SuiteScript using SuiteTalk?

Tags: netsuite

I am dealing with a question if it is possible to execute a SuiteScript inside of the NetSuite using SuiteTalk.

I have a workaround of using Web driver and SuiteLet where I am passing a URL with InternalID of the particular Script that I am executing.

Any ideas?

Thank you in Adnvance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a RESTLet that contains whatever logic you need and call it that way - much more secure than an externally available Suitelet, which has NO security.